# httpd logformat configuration - adding a format suffix to an existing logformat

Tags: apache

I am trying to define a new [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) by re-using an already existing LogFormat nickname.

Let's consider the following snipped (from the "[Log files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/logs.html#accesslog)" section of the httpd documentation):

```
SetEnv CACHE_MISS 1
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{CACHE_MISS}e" common-cache
CustomLog logs/access_log common-cache
```

I would like to know if there is a way to define the `common-cache` log format by re-using the `common` log format instead of hard coding `%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b`

I am asking this because I want to define a `base` log format in the core `httpd.conf` file and then define a `customized` log format, based on the `base` log format, in each of my virtual host config files

Note that I do not need a nickname for the customized log format, which means that a solution of one of the following forms will be sufficient:

```
## form 1
LogFormat *my customized format*
TransferLog logs/access_log

##form 2
CustomLog logs/access_log *my customized format*
```

Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Use a [piped log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped) to achieve this:

```
 CustomLog "|| customizer.sh logs/access_log 86400" foo_format
```

> The second argument specifies what will be written to the log file. It can specify either a nickname defined by a previous LogFormat directive, or it can be an explicit format string as described in the log formats section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see the idea, but I do no really see what the content of customizer.sh should be? A simple echo command that return the log pattern to add to the base log format (foo_format) ?